# Java: How to store List<Object> in OrientDB?

Tags: java, orientdb

Is there a sample code that shows how to store and retrieve List fields?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just create a class with, for example, a List. Example:

public class Order{
  ...
  List items;
  ...
}

Then:

```
ODatabaseObjectTx db = new ODatabaseObjectTx("local:/temp/db");
db.create();

db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Order.class);
db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(OrderItem.class);

Order o = new Order(234);
o.items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
o.items.add( new OrderItem('mouse', 10, 12.5) );

db.save( o );
```

Comment: you mean in my object: `List<Object> oj = new LinkedList<Object>();` what about getters and setters for this field?

Comment: Doesn't matter: OrientDB can access to internal fields even without getter/setter. But if you define them OrientDB will use them.